# When debugging in VS Code with an emulator, can I pin the emulator to a panel in VS code (rather than have it as a separate window?)

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

Is there a way to pin the emulation window to visual studio code, as a side panel (a bit like how you can have a 'widget inspector' panel). So I can view the UI of my flutter application.

Currently I am snapping the emulator to the left side of my screen, and the IDE to the right. But if I am following a tutorial, it gets difficult in terms of space. I don't necessarily need it to be the android emulator, it can be the windows emulator if necessary for now.

Comment: It is possible on Android Studio. 
but if your work with Mac, you can use split screen but it is still not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to pin the emulation window to Visual Studio Code as a side panel. However, you can use the emulator always on top setting, follow these steps:

1. Click on the three dots in the top right corner of the emulator window.
2. Select Settings.
3. Under General tab, check the box `Emulator always on top`.